# Bayesian Networks vs traditional stats approaches to Causal Inference?

Tags: causality, bayesian-network

I've been reading the 'book of why' by Judea Pearl and come to understand that Bayesian Networks can be used to establish causality given a directed acyclic graph (DAG) and that the methods are non-parametric. Throughout the book, the author drags Pearson and Fisher through the mud; it can be hard to tell what is an emotional reaction to resistance from the stats community vs genuine criticisms/improvements to traditional stats approaches to causal inference.

My question is: How are traditional approaches from stats different?

Comment: I have a similar sentiment to the one expressed in your second sentence. But your question seems a bit too broad.

Comment: @RichardHardy I see one upvote and two votes to close, so I edited and reduced scope of question

Comment: I've retracted my close vote, but I still think the question is a bit broad. Pearl himself outlines many of the differences between his approach and trad. stats. I wouldn't say Pearl "drags Pearson and Fisher through the mud"; he does critique their approach, but I think he's fair and says when he thinks they did the right thing.